# Where can I find 'Bookings' Data

Tags: opportunity, metadata

I am developing for salesforce and was told to look up a "Bookings" table in Salesforce. It is supposed to contain information such as the sales amount for an opportunity or some related transaction value.

I couldn't find any table with name bookings.

Where would these information be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard object called 'bookings' however a booking could be a Opportunity with a status of Closed Won indicating that you've closed that sales deal.

The Opportunity object has the amount of the sale on it and the related products which were part of the deal, etc.

Here's a link to how Opportunities are used in the sales process:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/admin_intro_opptys_leads/units/admin_intro_opptys_leads_opportunities

Here's some details about the Opportunity object itself:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm

Comment: Is there any reports / dashboard / interface in salesforce referring to the opportunities data you mentioned as bookings?

Comment: Salesforce has lots of standard Opportunity reports. Help & Training will be your friend in this area. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_oppforesales.htm